# Discord welcome message: Cannot read property 'MessageEmbed' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a basic welcome message embed. This is my `main.js` minus the login token:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const MessageEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();

const prefix = 'm.';
const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}
```

and this is `welcome.js` minus the definition of `channelId`:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'guildMemberAdd', 
    execute(member, Discord) {

        console.log('login');

        const message = `Welcome <@${member.id}> !`;
        const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(channelId);

        const joinEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`New member!`)
            .setDescription(message)
            .setColor("#fab9c7");
        
        channel.send({ joinEmbed });
     },
};
```

This is the full error message:

```
        const joinEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'MessageEmbed' of undefined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Al\Desktop\MaikaBot\events\welcome.js:11:39)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Al\Desktop\MaikaBot\main.js:17:44)
    at Client.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at Object.module.exports [as GUILD_MEMBER_ADD] (C:\Users\Al\Desktop\MaikaBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\GUILD_MEMBER_ADD.js:16:14)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Al\Desktop\MaikaBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Al\Desktop\MaikaBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Al\Desktop\MaikaBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Al\Desktop\MaikaBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\Al\Desktop\MaikaBot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:970:20)
```

Sorry if this is really basic I'm not very comfortable with javascript yet. I just can't seem to wrap my head around module syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Discord` is undefined in your module. This is because there is only one argument to the callback function for the `guildMemberAdd` event, which is a `GuildMember`.

Simply require discord.js in your module, or pass in Discord when calling `execute`

Comment: Am I not passing in Discord in line 3 of ```welcome.js```?

I did try the other way which is to just require discord.js in my module. I get a new```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message```, I checked the embed doc from Discord it looks like I'm using embeds correctly.

Comment: Update: I was missing ```embed:``` before the embed itself. So it's working now, thank you! (I'd still like to know how to do it the other way if it's possible)

Comment: @AlPhim simply declaring Discord in the exported function doesn't automatically make the argument available. You need to pass in the argument where you *call* the exported function, which in this case is your main.js (line 17).